# Javascript : before clicking, function executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: callback
    });
}

foo(function(result) {
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="foo();">Weather</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want after clicking button it should execute, but just after running it executes value. How to mix this mistake? Silly one may be

**EDIT:**

I tried earlier:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="temp"></p>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getWeather() {
  data_Json = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      data_Json = data;
      //alert("Weather Report: "+data_Json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }
  });
  return data_Json;
}

function temp() {
  //getWeather(data_Json);
  obj = JSON.stringify(getWeather(data_Json));
  alert("Got"+JSON.stringify(obj));
  //alert(JSON.stringify(getWeather()));
  document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = obj.main.temp;
alert("Temp : "+obj);
  }
</script>
</body>
<body>
<button onclick="getWeather();">Get Weather</button>
<button onclick="temp();">Temperature</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But this is not a good practice so I tried the first code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code actually *executes* the function itself.

```
foo(function(result) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

It's even more obvious if you omit the callback in the call.

```
foo(...);
```

You might want something similar to the following

```
function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: callback
    });
}

function myCallback(result) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}

<button onclick="foo(myCallback);">Weather</button>
```

Comment: exactly my friend.Short precise exact :)

Answer (score 3):

You call `foo` explicitly with `foo(function(result) {...`, so... it executes.

To clarify: the `onclick="foo();"` only governs what happens on the click event. The first call to `foo`, however, isn't bound to an event, so it executes regardless.

Comment: Actually I want to get return value of foo function from another function say goo() I mean onclick goo(), foo will execute and pass value to goo and then do something with the value and then say alert that value. I am not able to do that

Comment: In that case, please post your real code or something closer to it; what you have above doesn't resemble that closely enough for us to tell what your problem is.